# Story with a fake motorcycle cop

Tags: story-identification, philip-k-dick

I have a vague memory of a scene of a novel or short story. I am under the impression that it was by Philip K. Dick. A character is going to impersonate a motorbike cop and rehearses in a room (in front of a mirror?) what he will have to say to another character he is going to stop and ticket.

(I read it more than 20 years ago in an Italian translation, but the story should be older.)

I know this is very little to go by...

Comment: "Have you seen this boy?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time Out of Joint

> Time Out of Joint is a dystopian novel by Philip K. Dick, first published in novel form in the United States in 1959. An abridged version was also serialised in the British science fiction magazine [New Worlds Science Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Worlds_(magazine)) in several installments from December 1959 to February 1960, under the title Biography in Time.

-[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Out_of_Joint)

[The entire novel is here](http://www.novelhere.com/time-out-joint-philip-k-dick?)

> On the screen appeared the image of a man in uniform. Boots, brown pants stuffed into the boots, leather belt, pistol in holster, brown canvas shirt, necktie poking out at his collar, heavy brown jacket, visored cap, sun-glasses. The man in uniform turned around, showing himself from several sides. Then he climbed onto a motorcycle, kicked the motor into life, and roared off.
>
> The screen showed him riding along.
>
> "Fine," the young man wearing shorts and undershirt said. He got out his electric shaver, snapped it on, and, watching the screen, finished shaving.
>
> The highway patrolman on the screen began pursuing a car. After a while he caught up with the car and waved it to a stop at the side of the road. The young man, shaving reflexively, studied the expression on the highway patrolman’s face.
>
> The highway patrolman said, "All right, may I see your driver’s license please?"
>
> The young man said, "All right, may I see your driver’s license please?"
>
> The door of the trapped car opened and a middle-aged man wearing a white shirt and unpressed slacks got out, reaching into his pocket. "What’s the matter, officer?" he said.